# DreamHost VPS web server configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, dreamhost

I moved my 10+ rails applications to DreamHost VPS from shared hosting. A problem that I found was that the default value of PassengerMaxPoolSize is 4. That's way too small for me. To change that, I have to manage web server by myself.

I guess httpd.conf is the file that I have to manage. But I don't understand some part of it. For example, the following lines:

```
SetEnv dsid 19649082
SetEnv ds_id_19649082
```

Where do I get the values? If you have experience with that, can you show me how to manage that?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but had the same question myself today.
When you create the domain/hosting via the Dreamhost Domains Panel and assign it to your VPS, the "dsid" number can be found here:
/home/_domain_logs/DOMAINUSERNAME/DOMAIN/http.DSID#

The log file the system automatically creates has the DSID number in the http.## folder name.

Despite information out there, the DSID number is important to put in your httpd.conf when you manually set up a Virtual Host on your VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Are those settings a problem? If not, then you probably don't have to touch them. They're just [setting environment variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) that Apache modules and your Rails app can access.

The `dsid` stuff is probably added by Dreamhost to track which site a request is associated with.

Comment: Yes. I purchased 2GB and the recommended PassengerMaxPoolSize is 30 accrording to the Passenger Documentation. 4 is too small. Now I changed that to 30 and currently 17 instances are running. Maybe I need to ask DreamHost what dsid is. Thanks.